# How to read multiple lines with STDIN in PHP?

Tags: php, stdin

I have a file with multiple lines like this:

```
5 2 1
10 20 30
```

How do I read each of the lines and put the values in an array?

I'd like to have `$array1` to include values from the first line and `$array2` to include values from the second line.

I tried this without much success:

```
define("STDIN", "php://stdin");
$fr = fopen(STDIN, "r");
fscanf($fr, "%d\n", $array);
```

Comment: Do you know what `stdin` is? How do you invoke your script and pipe the file in?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this: https://amazon.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4fd6570bd51e1. In the `Use custom testcase...` option on that page, I type in my input and then use `fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $number);` to read the input. All I get is the first digit.

Comment: That's not what I asked. But use `fgecsv` with space as delimiter instead.